# Failure to decrypt a gpg file using a passphrase within unix

Tags: unix, gnupg, decrypt, passphrase

I'm trying to decrypt a file using the following command within a unix shell prompt:

`gpg --passphrase-file /path/to/passphrase/file --output /path/to/output/dir/full_db_restore --decrypt full_db_backup_current.tar.gpg`

I get the following error when running the command above:

```
gpg: 3DES encrypted data
gpg: problem with the agent: No pinentry
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

I have verified that pinentry is installed. I'm not sure if pinentry is the issue. I have a feeling it might be with the "No secret key" error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: good question but I think it should be moved to superuser, because that's not a programming related question.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered a solution to this.

```
/usr/bin/gpg --no-tty --batch --passphrase-file /path/to/passphrase/file --output   \
/path/to/output/dir/full_db_restore --decrypt full_db_backup_current.tar.gpg
```

The only difference is that I've added `--no-tty` and `--batch` options. After logging onto my unix server, I switch users from userA to userB. I'm assuming that because I switch users, there was an error. I'm not sure if this is the write solution as the options mentioned above are used when calling the command from a shell script. Any additional information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You must to use this command:

```
    gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 1 --passphrase-file /path/to/passphrase/file  
    --output /path/to/output/dir/full_db_restore full_db_backup_current.tar.gpg
```

**--batch**: is used in scripts for non-interactive mode (no asking);

**--passphrase-fd 1** together with **--passphrase-file**: to read the passphrase from a file.

If you use only --passphrase-file on *nix it will not work.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use below script

#! /bin/sh gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase='PASSWORD' --output /output/outputFileName /input/inputFileName